# Moblog and Channel Images

Tags: channel-images

I am wondering if there is a way to use the Channel Images (by Devdemon) fields with Moblog. I've tried a bit and have not found a way...yet. Tomorrow, though, is another day and I can give it more attention but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if someone has been successful.
Thanks to you all. This is a great resource and I hope it continues.
Carole

Comment: Can you please explain a little more about what Moblog is, and how exactly you want Channel Images to integrate with it? What exactly have you tried so far?

Comment: Adrian - may I introduce you to the [Moblog module](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/moblog/index.html). :)

Answer (score 1):

The moblog module unfortunately does not offer any integration with third-party fieldtypes, and has no extension hooks to allow you to do so. Honestly (as you can see by the comment by Adrian - an experienced EE developer - above) most people have no idea this module even exists.

So, you're either hacking core, or writing your own moblog-type module from scratch for this I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

The Moblog Module hasn't seen any new development for many years so I'm positive there is not a way to connect it to more modern modules without using is as a foundation for your own custom code.

Comment: Thank you, Anna. I didn't realize that it hadn't been in active development. It is still useful in many situations that I have so I may put in some time on it. Again, thank you.

Comment: It's one addon I've never actually used myself:)